# Evaluating beyond input conditions in R Shiny conditionalPanel

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I'm building a R Shiny dashboard, and am trying to implement conditionalPanels. Granted, I'm new to JavaScript. There's plenty of posts on SO about `conditionalPanels`, but every single one I've seen uses `input.something` in its condition expression, typically like this:

```
conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.tabs == 'correlation'",

    actionButton("generate_correlation", "Generate Heat Map")
  )
```

I know that the expression inside the condition statement is a string that is evaluated as a JavaScript expression, but I'm wondering if it's possible to access other variables and objects beyond `input`? Can it evaluate reactive functions, for instance? I would like to have a button be pressed, and then a new tab conditionally appear as a result. I've create

```
         tabPanel("Tab 1",
                  actionButton("dropColumnsComplete", "Next"))
```

Then, I've created a reactive expression on my server side to handle this:

```
  dropColumnsComplete <- reactive(input$dropColumnsComplete,{
    return(TRUE)
  })
```

Clicking the button triggers the `input$dropColumnsComplete` event, which should invoke the reactive expression that returns `TRUE` when the function `dropColumnsComplete()` is called. Then, I add in

```
     conditionalPanel(condition = "dropColumnsComplete()",
                      tabPanel("Tab 2")
                      ),
```

and I expect that pressing the button will cause Tab 2 to appear. I know I'm not accessing the `dropColumnsComplete()` inside the condition expression correctly- should it be `document.dropColumnsComplete()`? `shiny.dropColumnsComplete()`? There's a surprising lack of documentation on this, so I'm at a loss for how to access variables beyond `input$...` within JavaScript.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686581/make-conditionalpanel-depend-on-files-uploaded-with-fileinput?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no reason to write reactives to conditionally show/hide elements. Take a look at `shinyjs` instead by [Dean Attali](http://deanattali.com/shinyjs/)

Example of using `shinyjs`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("show", "Click me once to show stuff!"),
  actionButton("toggle", "Click me any times to toggle stuff!"),
  hidden(
    div(id = "d1",
      "Content hidden until button is clicked"
    )
  ),
  hidden(
    div(id = "d2",
        "Content toggled when button is clicked"
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observeEvent(input$show, {
    show("d1")
  })

  observeEvent(input$toggle, {
    toggle("d2")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks, but how would this work with `tabPanel`s in R? Since there isn't an element id I can reference as your case with `div` has.

Comment: Actually, I just found this great resource: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31703241/activate-tabpanel-from-another-tabpanel/31719425#31719425.